# Google Analytics: Getting visitor type

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to know if Google Analytics can provide me with information the type of location. For example: "University" or: "College" or: "Company" etc. (so *not* the name ISP name, but a type)

Answer (score 0):

No, Google does not identify visitors in any way. There are products that do something like this - the one I know is "Leadscout" by [wiredminds](https://www.wiredminds.de/1/home/) (not necessarily a recommendation, I' m just pointing out) - which analyze IPs/routing information to attribute incoming IP adresses to companies and organizations (commercial and expensive).